# Is the mix of tenses in this sentence correct?

Tags: tenses

The Constitution was envisioned as a reaffirmation of the fundamentals which are commonly held and have been accepted by the people. "was", "have", "are", in the same sentence?

Comment: Perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, this sentence uses the tenses correctly.

- "The Constitution" (noun) is something that **was** created in the past.
- The fundamentals are the *details* that are included in the Constitution and these fundamentals **are** held by people in the present.
- The reason people hold them *now* is because they **have** accepted them in their own past.